# C++ date difference-

Tags: c++

I have dates in string format-for example-

```
string date1= "06/12/2014"
string date2= "06/12/2015"
```

now my requirement is to find the no of difference days(date2-date1) between these two dates-

And it has to be used in C++ code-

Any quick help will be appreciated-thanks

Comment: Compute from a date the number of days passed since 00/00/0000 (including gap years, ...) and then build the difference.

Comment: The standard lib handles this pretty well http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/

Comment: @mrVoid-I have String in the form of date-small code snippet will be  helpful

Comment: You'll have to convert the dates into something that's suitable for calculation, either the time_ts require to use difftime as mrVoid suggested above, or if you can use boost, you could use their gregorian date class.

Comment: @Timo-small code will be helpful

Comment: @user3869192 - Surely a programmer can take the link and write the code. It is only a couple of lines and the link is good. guess it is too much effort to type it in yourself

Comment: Surely there has to be jobs for which you get paid to ask SO users to write code for you ...

Comment: @Ed Heal-you are correct ,but I am new to the programming and C++ too.@Unda-Thanks for writing,but for helping students you don't require money all time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

*Standard lib does it good*

Read the manual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void toTM(string date, struct tm *t) {
    stringstream ss(date);
    string month, day, year;

    getline(ss, month, '/');
    getline(ss, day, '/');
    getline(ss, year, '/');

    memset(t, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    t->tm_mday = stoi(day);
    t->tm_mon = stoi(month) - 1;
    t->tm_year = stoi(year) - 1900;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string date1 = "06/12/2014";
    string date2 = "06/12/2015";
    struct tm time1, time2;

    toTM(date1, &time1);
    toTM(date2, &time2);
    int diff = difftime(mktime(&time2), mktime(&time1));

    cout << diff / 60 / 60 / 24 << " days" << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```